# Intellisense for Visual Studio on variables defined as "var" that are collections

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 on a new computer and am having problems with intellisense.  It seems that all my "var" variables are not working with intellisense, but if I actually define what they are (string, int, ObjectName or whatever), everything works fine.

When I mouseover the defined variable, the tool tip says:

```
var user = DataAccess.User.Get(UserID);

mouseover tooltip =>  (local variable) var user
```

Again, if I explicitly define what it is, it's fine.

```
DataAccess.User user = DataAccess.User.Get(UserID);

mouseover tooltip =>  (local variable) DataAccess.User user
```

I'm really at a loss to know what to do with this.

**NOTE** DataAccess is its own project, so this may be a cross-project issue.

**NOTE** It also only appears to be an issue on collections (IQueryables, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this only happens with variables? and only in your project?.. not sure but if you'll like try installing "resharper" its a program that help you detect errors with your code and also manage a personalize intellisense

Comment: Yeah, only the variables defined with the "var" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... I had unknowingly introduced a build error that broke the intellisense, but it was on the web project, so I don't usually explicitly build that.  Well, maybe someone else will make the same mistake I did and find this answer.